# I run my project and it still installing for a long time the debug version but doesn't run on simulator

Tags: flutter

[image]

I downgrading gradle to 4.10.3 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0

Comment: Please share more details about what is happening and what you want to happen. "Doesn't run" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: I put these packages 
toast: ^0.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  flare_flutter: ^1.6.2
  material_search: ^0.2.8
  image_picker_modern: ^0.4.12+3
  flutter_cupertino_date_picker: ^1.0.12
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^0.1.7
 and downgrading gradle to 4.10.3 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc02
and run project on simulator 
it still installing for a long time  but doesn't open  on simulator.
I share a screenshot   for my issue.